# When disabling status Bar, the app doesn't receive clicks

Tags: android

```
  WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |

            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        localLayoutParams.height = (int) (25 * context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        view = new customViewGroup(context);

        manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

My app top buttons doesn't receive `click` events because of the top invisible `view`. Can you please suggest a way that I can disable `status bar`, without disabling app's top side?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom theme to hide your status bar instead. In your styles.xml create a custom theme:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And just add it in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
...
... 
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

Comment: This style hides the status bar, but you can still open it by swiping, I need to disable that functionality on my launcher app.